# How to solve Javascript error: "Error occurred, no handler for data"?

Tags: javascript, odata

I'm experimenting with OData and I'm trying to capture all "Categories" in the requested link below. Each Category will be displayed in a div. When I try to check the page it gives me the following error message: Error occurred, no handler for data. It just gives me a blank page. How to solve this problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1"); // 1.5.2
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="datajs-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      OData.defaultHttpClient.enableJsonpCallback = true;

      OData.read("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories",
        function(data, request) {
          var html = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            html += "<div>" + data.results[i].Name + "</div>";
          }
          document.getElementById("Categories").innerHTML = html;
        },
        function(err) {
          alert("Error occurred " + err.message);
        });

    });
  </script>
  <title>Categories</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Categories"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like:

1. Used datajs-1.1.2.min.js instead of datajs-1.0.1.min.js.
2. Changed in the for loop:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {

       OData.defaultHttpClient.enableJsonpCallback = true;

       OData.read("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories", function (data, request) {
         var html = "";
         for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
           html += "<div>" + data.results[i].CategoryName + "</div>";
         }
         document.getElementById("Categories").innerHTML = html;
       }, function (err) {
         alert("Error occurred " + err.message);
       });

     });
   ```

May be below like will help you.

http://datajs.codeplex.com/workitem/392

https://datajs.codeplex.com/discussions/344801

Answer (score 0):

If your service uses OData version 4 then DataJs will call the error handler because it doesn't know how to parse the response. If you look into datajs.js file you will see the "3.0" hard-coded in there, meaning this is the version for which was designed.

Here is a status report as of May 2014 that confirms the above: http://www.odata.org/blog/status-updates-of-odata-libraries-that-support-odata-version-4-0/. It seems there wasn't any update on datajs to handle OData v4.

For OData version 4 you can use another javascript library called Olingo as described here: http://olingo.apache.org/doc/javascript/index.html

Another library you can use is BreezeJs that has an adapter for version 4. See this other question: [Breeze | datajs - no handler for data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712606/breeze-datajs-no-handler-for-data/41447141#41447141)